# Running android app in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am new in Android.

I have downloaded Eclipse 3.4 and integrate with ADT and Android SDK r06.

My problem is that My Simulator is not working, it opens properly but the screen shows only "ANDROID.."

What should I do?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just wait as the emulator runs slower on desktop than actual device..takes a bout a minute to boot up the first time.